# How do I map list of strings into a list of objects in Ansible/Jinja2?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to build security groups rule and routes from a list of CIDRs, and can't quite get the mapping syntax right.

I have an list of cidrs:

```yaml
cidrs:
  - 10.12.0.0/16
  - 10.99.0.0/16
  - 192.168.128.0/24
```

And I'd like to transform it into a list of rules for a security group, such as:

```yaml
rules:
  - proto: all
    cidr_ip: 10.12.0.0/16
  - proto: all
    cidr_ip: 10.99.0.0/16
  - proto: all
    cidr_ip: 192.168.128.0/24
```

What's the syntax for performing this sort of transformation using Jinja2/Ansible filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Filter *combine* in *loop***

For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    cidrs:
      - 10.12.0.0/16
      - 10.99.0.0/16
      - 192.168.128.0/24
    protos:
      proto: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        rules: "{{ rules|default([]) +
                   [{'cidr_ip': item}|combine(protos)] }}"
      loop: "{{ cidrs }}"
    - debug:
        var: rules
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

  rules:
  - cidr_ip: 10.12.0.0/16
    proto: all
  - cidr_ip: 10.99.0.0/16
    proto: all
  - cidr_ip: 192.168.128.0/24
    proto: all
```

---

**2. Modified list and filter *combine* in *map***

If the input is a list of dictionaries, aka hashes, then simple *map* would do the job. For example, the playbook below gives the same result

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    cidrs:
      - cidr_ip: 10.12.0.0/16
      - cidr_ip: 10.99.0.0/16
      - cidr_ip: 192.168.128.0/24
    protos:
      proto: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        rules: "{{ cidrs|map('combine', protos)|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: rules
```

---

**3. Custom plugin and filter *combine* in *map***

The filter *product* seems a good candidate to start with the transformation of a simple list into a list of hashes. But, there is no filter in Ansible to transform a list of two items into a dictionary, AFAIK. Let's write such a filter. For example

```py
shell> cat filter_plugins/dict.py
def item2dict(t):
    h = {t[0]:t[1]}
    return h

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Ansible dict filters '''

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'item2dict': item2dict
        }
```

Then the playbook below gives the same result

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    cidrs:
      - 10.12.0.0/16
      - 10.99.0.0/16
      - 192.168.128.0/24
    protos:
      proto: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        rules: "{{ ['cidr_ip']|product(cidrs)|map('item2dict')|
                   map('combine', protos)|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: rules
```

Comment: The use of loop worked best for my use case. Option 2 would've been awesome, but I'm starting with a list of strings instead of a list of objects. I was also able to simplify the rule in Option 1 to just "{{ rules|default([]) + [{'cidr_ip': item, 'proto': 'all'] }}". Thanks!